# How to use remote: true to display 'show' template when clicking on link on index.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This looks to be extremely simple but somehow I am stuck, I have a profile scaffold and when the user clicks on profiles on index.html.erb,  I want the profile to open on same page rather then going to /profile/1

in index.html.erb

I have added

```
<div id="show_profile">
...
<td><%= link_to profile.name, profile, remote: true, :id => "show_profile" %></td>
...
</div>
```

in profile_controller.rb

I have added

```
def index
  ...
  format.js
end
```

I have also added show.js.erb with following code

```
$('#show_profile').('<%= j render("show") %>');
```

but when I click on the links, nothing happens, what am I missing ?